# Solve $2^x+2^{x+1}=1$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I need to solve $$2^x+2^{x+1}=1$$

I have set $y=2^x$ so I get
$$y+2y=1$$
$$3y=1$$
$$y=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$2^x=\frac{1}{3}$$

Now I used the $\log$ to get the $x$.

Now I get:

$$x = \log_2{\frac{1}{3}}$$

But the result is wrong, as [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex+%2B+2%5E(x%2B1)%3D1) shows:

$$x=-\frac{\log{3}}{\log{2}}$$

How should I get the $x$?

Comment: How do you know that the result is wrong?

Comment: Wolfram: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex+%2B+2%5E(x%2B1)%3D1

Comment: They are the same

Comment: $\log_2\left(\dfrac13\right) = -\log_23 = -\dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2}$

Comment: You never bothered to check if their numerical values are the same, did you?

Comment: No, didn't check it. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\log_2\left(\dfrac13\right) = \log_2\left(3^{-1}\right) = -\log_23 = -\dfrac{\log 3}{\log 2}$